# How to call homepage.dart void function deep inside of flutter widget tree?

Tags: callback, dart, flutter, inherited-widget

I don't understand scope model or inherited widget. But just calling a function deep inside a flutter widget tree I thought the inherited widget is best solution. I am asking this question in many places but seems either I am very new to the concept or the inherited widget not mature yet. I have widget tree as shown below;

```
- main.dart
  - homepage.dart with void _callBack
    - master.dart
      - details.dart
        - help.dart
```

I want to call void _callBack that reside inside homepage.dart from help.dart.

How to call homepage.dart void function deep inside of flutter widget tree?

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Ok, I found it and its working now. Here is a link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24673